# Adding DockPanel to StackPanel dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf

Here is the scenario, I have button named "ADD MORE" that add the combo box and button. I want to add the combo box and button which is under dockpanel. All DockPanels are under StackPanel.

After some event, I want to add another Dockpanel to StackPanel after the button event occurs in C# for WPF. I am doing it my adding Dockpanel to StackPanel, but I am getting exception.

Could you please help me out with this problem? I am getting this exception "Specified Visual is already a child of another Visual or the root of a CompositionTarget".

Regards,
Dev

Comment: What is the exception you are getting?

Comment: You're going to have better luck with people helping you if you're more specific.  The exact error would be a good start.  The code you're using that creates the error would be better.

Answer (score 2):

Hard to help you out when you don't provide your code, but here is an example of a DockPanel which is added to a StackPanel already existing on the form. Two buttons are added to the DockPanel to illustrate that it works.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DockPanel dp = new DockPanel();
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.Content = "Hello1";
        //Add the button to the DockPanel
        dp.Children.Add(btn);
        btn = new Button();
        btn.Content = "Hello2";
        //Add the button to the DockPanel
        dp.Children.Add(btn);
        //Add the DockPanel to the StackPanel
        stackPanel1.Children.Add(dp);
    }
```

Post your code if this simple example is of no help to you so that we can try and help you out.

Comment: Thanks for that. This is the code that I wrote manually. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8300318/duplicating-the-button-and-adding-it-to-dockpanel-in-wpf-c

Comment: I wanted to know, is there any way you can copy the UI item directly. Something like copy constructor of button.

If I have button in my XAML and I want to copy that button and add another in the DockPanel or adding Dockpanel in StackPanel, If I do that I was getting this exception "Specified Visual is already a child of another Visual or the root of a CompositionTarget"

Comment: @user1069622 There are no copy constructors in WPF. It wasn't designed to do such things, as I understand.