# Duplicating the button and adding it to dockpanel in WPF/C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to add the button to my `DockPanel` dynamically. I need to create the same button which exist in my dockpanel.

```
<Button Name="ImageMoreButton"
             DockPanel.Dock="Right"
             Command="{Binding LaunchLookup}" 
             Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}"
             Margin="2,0,2,0"
             Padding="3"
             Visibility="{Binding Definition.IsLookupImageButton, Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityConverter}}"
             IsEnabled="{Binding Locked, Converter={StaticResource invertedBooleanConverter}}">
             <Image Name="button_image" Source="search_button_rest.png"/>
</Button>
```

Here is my C# code.

```
d.Name = VariableArg.Name + index;
d.Margin = VariableArg.Margin;

item.Command = ImageMoreButton.Command;
item.Style = ImageMoreButton.Style;
item.Name = ImageMoreButton.Name + index;
item.Visibility = ImageMoreButton.Visibility;
item.Padding = ImageMoreButton.Padding;
item.Margin = ImageMoreButton.Margin;
item.IsEnabled = ImageMoreButton.IsEnabled;
item.Height = ImageMoreButton.ActualHeight;
item.Width = ImageMoreButton.ActualWidth;
DockPanel.SetDock(item, Dock.Right);
```

Let me know if this is the correct way to that.

Comment: Is you code doing something? If it doesn't maybe you forgot to add `item` in your form

Comment: Do you really need to do this dynamically in code?

If you just need 2 buttons that may be hidden, just write them both in XAML and manipulate `Visibility`. If you need to have a button per item of some collection, you'd better use an `ItemsControl` to automatically generate buttons for you.

Additional info on your case would be appreciated.

Comment: No. I need n number of buttons depending on the configuration.

Comment: I have add more button link in my Stack Panel. On Click of this link, I need to add the Dockpanel which consists of button, Combo Box and CheckBox. When user clicks on add more, then I want to add the above mentioned dockpanel. Any suggestions to handle in a better way?

Answer (score 1):

WPF Controls cannot be added to two different parent controls. If you wish to add a copy of an item at runtime, you need to create a new object entirely, not re-use an existing item.

That said, since your buttons represent a Configuration setting, I would recommend you use something like an `ItemsControl` that is bound to a collection of data objects, with the `Button` being used as the `ItemTemplate`.

For example, suppose you had an `ObservableCollection<MySetting>` collection called `Settings`. You could then write the following XAML:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Settings}">

    <!-- ItemsPanelTemplate -->
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <DockPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <!-- ItemContainerStyle -->
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" Value="Right" />
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>

    <!-- ItemTemplate -->
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.LaunchLookup, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" 
                    Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}"
                    Margin="2,0,2,0"
                    Padding="3"
                    Visibility="{Binding Definition.IsLookupImageButton, Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityConverter}}"
                    IsEnabled="{Binding Locked, Converter={StaticResource invertedBooleanConverter}}">
                 <Image Source="search_button_rest.png"/>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Then to add new items, you would simply add items to the `ObservableCollection`

```
Settings.Add(new MySetting());
```

For other examples using an `ItemsControl`, check out [this post I wrote](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-itemscontrol-example/)

Answer (score 0):

If you use this code a lot I suggest you define an extension method on Button class. like this :

```
  public static class ButtonExtension
    {
        public static Button Clone(this Button myButton, int index)
        {
            var newButton = new Button
                                {
                                    Command = myButton.Command,
                                    Style = myButton.Style,
                                    Name = myButton.Name + index,
                                    Visibility = myButton.Visibility,
                                    Padding = myButton.Padding,
                                    Margin = myButton.Margin,
                                    IsEnabled = myButton.IsEnabled,
                                    Height = myButton.ActualHeight,
                                    Width = myButton.ActualWidth
                                };
              return newButton;
        }
    }
```

which you can use later like :

```
  var newButton = ImageMoreButton.Clone(index);
  DockPanel.SetDock(newButton, Dock.Right);
```

Comment: I am a newbie to WPF. Please bear with me for my naive questions. 
What will be the value of Style and Command property in buttons by direct assignment?

Comment: @user1069622 Don't worry, they will be the same as on your original button. And the result will be quite natural.

Comment: @user1069622 as Pavel Gatilov mentioned since it is reference type. they will be similar (sharing the same style)

Comment: Right now, I don't see the same property. In this property, we are setting Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}". Here it will adjust the size of combo box and buttons. If you expand your window the width of your combo box will also expand.

However, by adding dynamically I don't see that property.

Comment: I don't this has to do with the fact that the style is set through StaticResource. I just tried, and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

Talking about "a better way", I recommend you to get faimliar with the [MVVM Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) since it's very powerful in simplifying the UI code. Also, it seems to be a widespread best practice for WPF programming since WPF has great infrastructure for it. There certainly is a learning curve, but once you understand it, you'll solve such puzzles easily. I could provide a sample, but I'm not sure that it would be useful here.

If you need a solution right now, you can use your code, it seems to be fine. But don't forget to add new controls to the parents:

```
parentPanel.Children.Add(item);
```